# resize view during scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

I am trying to build a UI with two portions

```
 _________
|    A    |
|         |
 ---------
|   B     |
|         |
 ---------
```

A and B start with the same size. When I scroll up on portion B, I want portion A to shrink to `20%` while B gets `80%`. When I scroll down on B, I want A to return to the 50%. I see this kind of design frequently on android. I am sure the reason I can't find it is because I don't know the official name. Perhaps someone here can help guide me a bit.

I am a bit "old school" so I am thinking of LinearLayout with two children fragments both starting with weight 1; then when I scroll fragment B, I can resize the weights. But perhaps that is not the way. Thanks for any guidance.

One more thing: the content of B may be a listView or a long textView (dynamically swappable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at **Collapsing Toolbars** section in [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). Recently Google added support library to make easier this kind of transformations.